# How to bind button to button in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to disable button1, if button2 is enabled is there anyway I can do that in javafx?

```
btnArrived.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.isEmpty(fieldConfirmation.textProperty())
    );
```

I have code like this but only works on binding button to textfield

Comment: there's a `not` binding that you can use to bind the first disabled to the second disabled

Comment: how? can you give precise example?

Comment: Honestly don't see how _bind one boolean to the negated other boolean_ can pose a problem - there's the api doc of Bindings to read and tons of tutorials for examples ...

Comment: maybe I misunderstand what you are after, so please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Without knowing the context you need, this will bind button 1 to be disabled as long as button 2 is enabled: `btn1.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.not(btn2.disableProperty()));`

Comment: Check out the classes in [`javafx.beans.binding`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html) package to see all the built-in functionality you can use. The [`Bindings`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) class in particular provides many convenience methods. Also note the `XXXExpression` classes which provide a fluent API for many of the `Bindings` methods. The standard property implementations (e.g. `BooleanProperty`) all inherit from the corresponding expression classes (e.g. `BooleanExpression`).